# Advice on Speeding up SciPy Custom Distribution Sampling & Fitting

Tags: scipy, sampling

I am trying to fit a custom distribution to a large (~O(500,000) measurements) dataset using scipy. I have derived a theoretical PDF based on some other factors, but both by hand and using symbolic integration software I cannot find an exact form of the CDF.

Currently, simply evaluating 1000 random samples from my custom distribution is expensive, which I believe is due to the need to invert an unknown CDF. If I cannot find an explicit form of the CDF and it's inverse, is there anything else I can do to speed up usage of this distribution?

I've used maple, matlab and Sympy to try and determine a CDF, yet none give a result. I also tried down-sampling my data whilst still retaining the tail attributes, but this still required so much data that doing anything with the distribution was slow.

My distribution is a sub-class of SciPy's rv_continuous class.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can try to use a discrete rvs based on the data histogram, not very elegant, but likely more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you want to sample from a [Kernel Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) of the probability distribution.  While Scipy does offer a Gaussian Kernel package, for that many measurements you would be much better off using [sklearn's implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html).  A good resource with code examples can be found on Jake VanderPlas's [blog](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/).